# Laravel XSS Attack Protection

Tags: laravel, xss

I'm using "summernote" rich content editor for inserting content for my website.
But I want to make some "XSS protections".

For example If user insert data like;

```
<p>hi there</p><script>alert("deneme")</script>
```

I want to show HTML but stop script etc. harmful content.

```
{!! $find->description !!}}
```

returns alert dialog.
And I want to stop that things.

Whats the resolve of that?
How can we make XSS protection?

Comment: I use [this package](https://github.com/tgalopin/html-sanitizer) it's not bad

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the PHP [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function, which removes unwanted tags. You can whitelist the tags you want present in your output HTML and the other harmful tags will be wiped away.

Would be something like:

```php
{!! strip_tags($find->description, '<p><i><br><strong>...') !!}}
```

Comment: Why not htmlentities?

Comment: I believe `htmlentities` would parse all tags, without whitelisting. So the ones he wants to preserve would be also removed.